# Running a Java Script in AppleScript

Tags: java, jar, applescript

Okay, so I'm trying to open a .jar file but no matter what I try, it always comes up with an error.

I have tried:

```
to run

    set current_path to POSIX path of (path to me) as string

    set pathto to current_path & "Contents/Resources/TechnicLauncher.jar"

    tell application "Finder" to open file pathto

end run
```

With the error:

> error "Finder got an error: Can’t get file \"/Applications/Technic
>   Launcher.app/Contents/Resources/TechnicLauncher.jar\"." number -1728
>   from file "/Applications/Technic
>   Launcher.app/Contents/Resources/TechnicLauncher.jar"

And this:

```
to run

    set current_path to POSIX path of (path to me) as string

    set pathto to quoted form of current_path & "Contents/Resources/TechnicLauncher.jar"

    do shell script pathto

end run
```

With the error:

> error "sh: /Applications/Technic
>   Launcher.app/Contents/Resources/TechnicLauncher.jar: Permission
>   denied" number 126

I don't how I can make this work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.  I have not tried it on my system because I have no jar files I would like to open.  I think this will work for you though.

```
set TechnicLauncher to (path to me as string) & "Contents:Resources:TechnicLauncher.jar"
tell application "Jar Launcher" to open TechnicLauncher
```

This should also work for you.

```
set TechnicLauncher to path to resource "TechnicLauncher.jar"
tell application "Jar Launcher" to open TechnicLauncher
```

But the file TechnicLauncher.jar...  Must be located inside the resources folder of the Script bundle or script application you have created.

Answer (score -1):

If you are just trying to launch it, given the jar is wrapped in a regular .app - have you tried

```
tell application "Technic Launcher"
    activate
end tell
```